# Managing focus between multiple CDHtmlDialog windows

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I create a modal CDHtmlDialog as my root window, and then create a modeless CDHtmlDialog window. Based on the events, clicking between the two windows shifts focus, but the root window is always in the back. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the desktop didn't seem to help.. I suspect because of the behavior of CDialogs. I fixed it by creating a hidden, root window, and making all of my dialogs (CDHtmlDialog's) children of that.

Answer (score 0):

The modeless dialog is alway on-top of the the root dialog is because the modeless dialog is created as a child of the root dialog. You can change this by making the modeless dialog a child of the desktop window instead as follows:

```
m_MyModelessDlg.Create(IDD_DIALOG1, GetDesktopWindow());
m_MyModelessDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```